# NullpointerException when retract fact in drl

Tags: drools

I received a `NullPointerException` when running rules; i have simplified the DRL file to reproduce the problem.

These are my versions:

- KIE_VERSION:7.53.0.Final
- jboss/business-central-workbench-showcase:latest

```
rule "retract"
no-loop
when

then
  retract( new String("myString"))
end
```

When I fire this rule, Drools throws a `NullPointerException`.

I have testet it in both equality mode and identity mode.

In equality mode, it fails *unless* a Fact `new String("myString")` was previously inserted into working memory.

Is this a bug? How do I avoid it?

Thanks, Saverio

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your rule.

The `retract` action is intended to remove a fact from working memory. In your code, you're trying to remove something that is not in working memory.

Here's a simple example for how this is supposed to work. Let's say we have some rules that key off of an object called `MyFact` that has some properties. So we have some rules that look like this:

```
rule "Example rule 1"
when
  MyFact( value == "foo" )
then
  // do something for 'foo'
end

rule "Example rule 2"
when
  MyFact( value == "bar" )
then
  // do something for 'bar'
end
```

Now, as long as we have a `MyFact` instance in working memory, these rules will be evaluated. So to keep these rules from firing, we can retract the fact -- but we have to retract the *instance*.

Example of the retraction:

```
rule "Retract fact when value is 'abc'"
when
  $f: MyFact( value == "abc" ) // $f is the instance
then
  retract($f)
end
```

We're not retracting arbitrary data -- we retract the *specific fact instance* we want to retract.

If I tried to retract something not in working memory -- then the NullPointerException makes total sense. You can't retract something that's not there, so when the Drools engine can't find the thing you've requested it throws the exception.